# Adding Repos to a team in Github

Tags: curl, github

I am having trouble on using the github api to add the Repos to a team in Github Enterprise

according to GitHub API: i should call:

```
PUT /teams/:team_id/repos/:owner/:repo
```

and iam making the below call using my access token

```
curl -H "Authorization: token personal_access_token" https://api.github.com/teams/test-team/repos/mohit/test_data
```

I received the  json data:

```
{
    "message": "Bad credentials",
    "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

here is the link for the documentation: https://developer.github.com/v3/teams/#add-or-update-team-repository

Iam not able to add Repos to team.
How to proceed with adding Repos to a team in an organization in Github Enterprise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When making the curl command, the Authorization header should look like this:

`-H "Authorization: token <PERSONALACCESSTOKEN>"`

So a full curl put command would look like this:

`curl -H "Authorization: token <PERSONALACCESSTOKEN>" -X PUT https://api.github.com/teams/<TEAMID>/repos/<ORGANISATION>/<REPO>`

To get the team ID you can list all your Organisation teams as follows:

`curl -H "Authorization: token PERSONALACCESSTOKEN" -X GET https://api.github.com/orgs/<ORGANISATION>/teams`

If you are self hosting your GitHub Enterprise then replace
`https://api.github.com`
with
`https://<HOSTNAME>/api/v3/`

Further reading:

API Authentication: https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

Listing teams: https://developer.github.com/v3/teams/#list-teams

Comment: Glad to hear it @mohitsehrawat - Also worth a https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: is there a way we can pass password instead of token?

Comment: and what if we are using Single Sign On as our login?

Comment: If you want to use basic authentication with curl to interact with the API you can do the following:

`curl -u "<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>" -get <APICALL>`

There isn't a single sign on option, to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Also important here is to check security we are working with. I had been struggling to use the "Authentication: token xxxxx" or even "Basic", while it only could work when I passed the command with "Bearer" as in 
`curl -v -X PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer psw"  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" https://api.github.com/orgs/your_org/teams/your_team_slug/repos/your_org/your_repo -d '{"permission":"admin"}'`

Here my psw is personal_access_token.